# Which comes first? Class, use case diagrams or dive into code using TDD?

Tags: testing, tdd, ooad

Which comes first? Doing proper oo analysis and design and create uml digrams then TDD cycle or just dive into code using TDD cycle?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: whatever works best in the situation.

Slightly longer: TDD typically works best as a feedback mechanism. This doesn't mean that thinking ahead isn't allowed. Quite the contrary, thinking ahead is fine, but what's at least as important is to reflect on how the plans unfold.

As Eisenhower put it:

> Plans are worthless, but planning is everything

In programming, most people's experience is that Big Design Up-Front rarely works, because compilers and interpreters are much more rigid and literal than you can imagine when planning.

Or, as Jack Reeves expressed it in the 1992 essay *What Is Software Design?*, the code *is* the design. You can't really design the code *before* you write it.

TDD gives you feedback about your design ideas as you go. Is this API easy to use? Does the implementation behave predictably?

You'll often find that what initially sounded like a good idea turns out to work poorly in practice. Whenever that happens, you use that feedback to adjust how to progress.

Comment: First of all thank you for your response. And I am a great fan of your book on dependency injection. Yes. I read it. What prompted me to ask this question is because before I knew TDD I'm used to the practice of OOAD. Writing use cases, use case diagrams & class diagrams, etc. because that was part of the SDLC. then TDD comes along should I forgo the class digrams that I'm used to making? Or should I make class diagrams then when I start coding then I do TDD?

Comment: I did the latter and what I realized is that doing TDD with a class & sequence digrams feels like having a cheat sheet the class diagram itself is already the design not much to reap in TDD but the tests for regression purposes. What would you do if you have a new project? What is your usual SDLC flow? UML then TDD? or TDD directly without UML?

Comment: also my initial UMLs are not final and are revised as the project proceeds therefore I dont do BDUF.

Comment: Also at what phase in the sdlc does tdd belong? After object design(ooad)? . Thanks!

Comment: @JohnPatrick In 20+ years, I've never meat a programmer that does UML, and I've no idea what SDLC is.

Comment: Hahaha... Okay fair enough..  SDLC - Software development lifecycle. I think its okay to do class diagrams and use TDD when you start coding to get the feedback and adjust how to progress. Thanks Mark!